# socket.io stop working if connection rewrite from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, websocket, socket.io

**Work:**

> I am working on socket.io, and just hide a port number, and redirect domain to domain:{port}

I have 3 domains, all working from 2 years, and suddenly 1 socket.io stops accepting if URL comes from rewrite.

**SERVER 1, example1.com/_____** rewrite with htaccess

```
.htaccess on server_1
RewriteRule ^socket2/(.*)$ ws://example_2.com:3000/$1  [P,QSA,L] #Working
RewriteRule ^socket3/(.*)$ ws://example_3.com:3000/$1  [P,QSA,L] #Not working

# Direct URL Working: ws://example_3.com:3000
```

**On Server 3, example_3.com,**

If i entered full URL "ws://example_3.com:3000" its working, if i write .htaccess rewrite rules on server1, then its not working.

**My Diagnoses On server3:**

- Socket.io working 100% OK.
- Socket connect and disconnect after milliseconds if URL from htaccess rewrite

I need help in finding out the exact issue and location.  I just want to hide the Port number and rewrite wss:// to ws://

Comment: This actually is not a classical rewrite, but a proxy you implemented. Since both rules are identical there is no difference in behavior. The only thing that could have different behavior is those two servers example_2 and example_3, but that has nothing to do with your rewriting. You will need to start debugging: so go, dive into the log files of both that rewriting server and the backend servers to find a first hint on what the actual cause is.

Comment: there is nothing in apache log and socket logs, also i didn't implement any proxy. its just rewrite and basic socket.io

Comment: I think you want to start reading the documentation of the tool you use. Especially the explanation about the `P` flag you use in your rule. "P" stands for "proxy" ...